# insert array to Google spreadsheet using python

Tags: python, arrays, insert, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

how can i insert an array one time into Google spreadsheet using python, the array should not be uploaded cell by cell. my code upload one cell at a time which is too slow.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gdata.spreadsheet.service
from array import *

email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
password = 'mypassword'
spreadsheet_key = '1233...key...1234' # key param
worksheet_id = 'od6' # default

rows=[]
def main():
    client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
    #client.debug = True
    client.email = email
    client.password = password
    client.source = 'test client'
    client.ProgrammaticLogin()


    rows.append({'id':'0','title':'First'})
    rows.append({'id':'1','title':'Second'})
    for i in range(2,101):
        rows.append({'id':str(i),'title':'First'})

    for raw in rows:
        try:

            client.InsertRow(raw, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)
        except Exception as e:
            print e

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```